# Ripple effect like a checkbox

Tags: android, android-menu

How to use the same ripple effect as the checkbox on the menu buttons. That is, the color of the waves varies depending on the inclusion.
At the moment, like this:

menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/elect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_elect_off"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/menu_elect"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Java

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_rule, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.elect);
        item.setChecked(rule.isElect());
        item.setIcon(rule.isElect() ? R.drawable.ic_elect_on : R.drawable.ic_elect_off);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.elect) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            item.setIcon(item.isChecked() ? R.drawable.ic_elect_on : R.drawable.ic_elect_off);

            rule.setElect(item.isChecked());
            Labs.get(getActivity()).updateRule(rule);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I tried to do it like this, and it worked, but of the minuses - problems with the width of the button, a lot of code.

menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/elect"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_elect"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Java

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_rule, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.elect);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) item.getActionView();
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.elect);
        checkBox.setChecked(rule.isElect());

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                rule.setElect(checkBox.isChecked());
                Labs.get(getActivity()).updateRule(rule);
            }
        });
    }
```

elect drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_elect_off" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_elect_on" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

menu/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/elect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_elect_off"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/menu_elect"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Java

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_rule, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.elect);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.ic_elect);
        item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO
                //bonus
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotation);
                item.getActionView().startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

layout/ic_elect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@null"
    android:translationX="12dp"
    android:button="@drawable/ic_elect" />
```

drawable/ic_elect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_elect_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_elect_off" />
</selector>
```

**bonus**
anim/rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="72"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="200"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```